# How to get Bundle state in my activity for menu item

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I have an application android where to start step one `bundle.putString ("statusLogin", "unlogged");` referring to my state of login, and so some features hidden buttons.

In my menu item an option "login as admin" that after the login has been carried out step a new parameter for the bundle: `bundle.putString ("statusLogin", "Logged")` and so I set visible the buttons allowed only to administrator .

Until then fine, but that in menu item possess the button "Init" where I would need to seek the status of Bundle without creating a new one so i can verify that it is logged in or not and show buttons allowed.

This is my main activity

```
public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("statusLogin", "Unlogged");
            TelaInicialFragment fragobj = new TelaInicialFragment();
            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.principal, fragobj).commit();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_principal, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    public static PrincipalActivity newInstance(Context context) {
        PrincipalActivity principalActivity = new PrincipalActivity();
        return principalActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.init:
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("statusLogin", "Unlogged");
                TelaInicialFragment fragobj = new TelaInicialFragment();
                fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.principal, fragobj).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.sincronizar:

                break;
            case R.id.logarAdmin:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.principal, new LoginFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.sair:
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I check the `Bundle` state to ensure that the user is currently authenticated?

Comment: When did you get the information about the authentication?

Comment: when I click on my menu item "LoginAdmin" goes to a fragment with a login screen where there checks. The login and password is an internal JSON. After logging be done I redirect to the Home screen passing new Bundle

          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("statusLogin", "Logged");
            TelaInicialFragment fragobj = new TelaInicialFragment();
            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.principal, fragobj).commit();

Comment: Did you mean that you want to get the bundle inside the fragment?

Comment: No, i need get bundle in main activity for my menu item, rather than creating a new one as I am doing in "init"

Comment: Create a instance variable and set it when you get the first value.

Comment: Alright, I thought about creating a variable String statusLogin on my main activity and pass it to the bundle, but as a value for step she made after login?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point...

Comment: send me a simple example in code please

Comment: can someone help me?